# Flutter setState is reverting

Tags: dart, flutter, setstate

When I `setState` and add an image to the `_images` array, it appears to have added, but then it quickly reverts:

[image]

This form is loosely following [Brian Egan's redux architecture example](https://github.com/brianegan/flutter_architecture_samples/blob/4bf497090662daec3b5d8b1c93b0a93af9aee3eb/example/bloc_flutter/lib/screens/add_edit_screen.dart):

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

class Note {
  final String comments;
  final List<String> images;

  Note({
    this.comments,
    this.images,
  });
}

class AddNote extends StatefulWidget {
  final Note note;
  final bool isEditing;

  AddNote({
    this.note,
    this.isEditing,
  });

  @override
  _AddNoteState createState() => _AddNoteState();
}

class _AddNoteState extends State<AddNote> {
  static final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  static final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  List<String> _images;
  String _comments;

  Note get _note => widget.note;
  bool get _isEditing => widget.isEditing;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _images = _note.images;
    _comments = _note.comments;

    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          _isEditing ? "Edit Note" : "Create Note",
        ),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              _photoPickerField(),
              _notesField(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _photoPickerField() {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: _selectPicture,
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey, width: 1,),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(const Radius.circular(10)),
            ),
            child: SizedBox(child: Icon(Icons.camera_alt), width: 110, height: 110,)
          ),
        ] + _imagesRowItems(),
      ),
    );
  }

  List<Widget> _imagesRowItems() {
    return _images.map((image) {
      return SizedBox(
        height: 110,
        width: 110,
        child: Image.file(File(image), height: 110, width: 110, fit: BoxFit.cover),
      );
    }).toList();
  }

  Future _selectPicture() async {
    return ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery)
      .then((file) {
        setState(() {
          _images.add(file.path);
        });
    });
  }

  Widget _notesField() {
    return TextFormField(
      maxLines: 2,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
      initialValue: _comments,
      onSaved: (String value) => _comments = value,
    );
  }
}
```

Note that the comments field keeps its state without issue. How can I add to the images array in a way that will maintain its new state?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is that you're setting variables inside the `build()` method of the Widget state, but the build method is called every time you call `setState()` because your variables have changed, so it resets the images and comments.

To fix it, you should initialize your variables in the `initState()` method, like this:

```
class _AddNoteState extends State<AddNote> {
  ...
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _images = _note.images;
    _comments = _note.comments;
  }
}
```

And remove them from the `build()` method.